Uniform convergence of a series of diffrentiable functions
Let $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}u_n(x)$ be a series of differentiable functions defined on the closed interval $[a,b]$, which convergences pointwise. Suppose that the sequence of the partial sum $\{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{\mathrm{d}u_i(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}\}$ is uniformly bounded on $[a,b]$. Show that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}u_n(x)$ convergences uniformly on $[a,b]$.
When the condition that the sequence of the partial sum is uniformly bounded, it may be helpful to use Dirichlet's criterion. However, how to connect the partial sum of derivatives to the series of the original functions?

@RRL Thanks. Suppose that $|\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{\mathrm{d}u_i(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}|\leq M$, then $|\sum\limits_{i=n}^{n+p}(u_i(x)-u_i(c))|\leq M|x-c|$. Then $|\sum\limits_{i=n}^{n+p}u_i(x)|\leq M|x-c|+\varepsilon$. Then what can we obtain?

Sorry that was a false lead, but worth considering.

Look at  this applied to the sequence of partial sums

@RRL Great! Thank you.
